# Disable script from git SCM changelog in Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a question when I use pipeline with git SCM, currently I push all Jenkinsfile script in git with master branch. But when I modify one Jenkinsfile script when the another pipeline job be trigger will only show the changes, It's very upset when I only when to check build changes.

for example: 
I config pipeline with git SCM (git: xxx/jenkinsJob, branch: master, script: a.jenkinsfile)

```
# a.jenkinsfile
stage('Checkout external proj') {
    steps {
        git branch: 'my_specific_branch',
            credentialsId: 'my_cred_id',
            url: 'ssh://git@test.com/proj/test_proj.git'
    }
}
```

After I modify b.jenkinsJob in git://xxx/jenkinsJob, when I trigger e A pipeline job,
the A job will show two git change for "xxx/jenkinsJob" and "git@test.com/proj/test_proj"
like:

```
# changes
b.jenkinsfile change message 1
b.jenkinsfile change message 2
b.jenkinsfile change message 3
a.jenkinsfile change message 2
..
test_proj change message
```

I know how to disable changelog in jenkinsfile.

```
git changelog: false, branch: 'my_specific_branch', url: 'ssh://git@test.com/proj/test_proj.git'
```

But in jenkins job configuration page, can not find any way to do that..

https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/ 
[image: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/]

Is there any way to avoid disable changelog in jenkins pipeline script for Git SCM ?, let only show test_proj changes.

thanks!

Comment: There is an open request for this feature [JENKINS-46922](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-46922)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I use this way to clear changeLog, use **currentBuild.getChangeSets().clear()**

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {       
        script {
          currentBuild.getChangeSets().clear()
        }
        git branch: "master", url: 'ssh://xxx/test.git'            
      }
    }  
  }
}
```